# Quicksort maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've implemented a quicksort algorithm to practice Python, here's my code:

```
def sort(array):   
    if len(array) > 1:
        pivot = array[0]
        left = []
        right = []
        equal = []
        for x in array:
            if x < pivot:
                left.append(x)
            elif x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            else:
                right.append(x)
        return sort(left)+equal+sort(right)
    return array
```

Now, the algorithm is working fine, but if I remove the `equal` list and do my loop like this:

```
    for x in array:
        if x < pivot:
            left.append(x)
        else:
            right.append(x)
    return sort(left) + sort(right)
```

I get the maximum recursion depth error when I try to sort the `right` list. It's not because that list also contains the equal elements, I tested it with very small lists. I'm feeling that this will be some really stupid mistake on my part, but I've had no luck in finding it so far.

Comment: Why do you think you don't need the `equal` list?

Comment: I was going with the intuition that it would make the code a bit cleaner and simpler. @lvc's solution with pop(0) is what I should've actually done for this approach, but on second thought, keeping an `equal` list is the better practice because I won't have to keep sorting everything that would've gone in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may look like you don't need the `equal` list, but its presence is critical. By putting the elements that go there into the `right` list, you force the algorithm to keep `sort()`ing elements that are already sorted. That's why your recursion limit is exceeded.

By adding a `print "sorting", array` at the start of your function, you can see what happens:

```
>>> sort([3,1,2])
('sorting ', [3, 1, 2])
('sorting ', [1, 2])
('sorting ', [])
('sorting ', [1, 2])
('sorting ', [])
('sorting ', [1, 2])
('sorting ', [])
... etc. until crash
```

Answer (score 2):

The pivot always goes into `right` as the zeroth element, and gets chosen again when you recurse on `right`. Since `right` also contains everything that is equal to or bigger than that, the next call will put *all* of the current elements into  the new `right`.

It will only ever reduce to one element if the pivot is the unique largest item in the list - which ultimately means that in *any other case* than your list having no duplicates and already being sorted in descending order, you will recurse indefinitely.

You don't need to have an `equal` *list*, but you do need to take at least the chosen pivot out of the recursion, so the next call down choses a different one. So choose it this way:

```
pivot = array.pop(0)
```

and adjust your reconstruction of the sorted list:

```
return sort(left) + [pivot] + sort(right)
```